# Translation of a plane with known normal.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, plane-curves

How to translate a plane with equation $ax+by+cz=d$ by a distance vector $<i, j, k>$. ?

Eg. Plane $x + y + z = 1$ to position $<2, 2, 2>$. If you can use this example to explain.

Comment: What does a plane `in position <2, 2, 2>` mean?

Comment: A more standard way to ask this: How do I find the plane which is parallel to a given plane and which passes through a given point?

Comment: @Bernard thats a mistake. I meant the distance i.e 2 units in each direction. Or sqrt(12)

Comment: I am sorry, but the interpretation of @Bernard is the right one if one follows your text because a "position" means a point. You should modify your text by saying that $(2,2,2)$ is a translation vector.

Comment: I'm a tad confused now. Do you want the parallel plane passing through (2,2,2), or do you want to shift all points in the original plane by (2,2,2)? (The normal form given in my answer works for either, but the logic is slightly different.)

Comment: @user1965914 I am happy that you have cancelled this filthy word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a general answer: if $\vec n$ is a normal vector to an affine plane $\Pi$, the equation of this plane can be written in the form
$$\overrightarrow{OM}\cdot\vec n= c$$
Suppose we translate  plane $\Pi$ by vector $\vec  v$, and set $\;\Pi'=\Pi+\vec v$. A point $M'\in \Pi'$ is the translated of point $M\in \Pi$, hence $\overrightarrow{OM}=\overrightarrow{OM'}-\vec v$. So an equation of $\Pi'$ is simply
$$\overrightarrow{OM}\cdot\vec n=(\overrightarrow{OM'}-\vec v)\cdot\vec n=c\iff \color{red}{\overrightarrow{OM'}\cdot\vec n=c+\vec v\cdot\vec n}$$

In the present case, one obtains
$$x+y+z=1+6=7.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: A plane passing through a point $\mathbf{x}_0$ with normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ can be specified as $\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)=0.$